# Why is Parametric/Vector arc length the integral of speed?

Tags: calculus, parametric

$$\mathrm{Speed}=\lvert\mathrm{velocity}\rvert$$

$$\mathrm{speed}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^{\!2}}$$

The parametric speed formula is based on the Pythagoras' theorem using a triangle formed by $\mathrm dy$ and $\mathrm dx$, with the length/magnitude of the hypotenuse being the speed. I think that makes sense to me.

But, what is the conceptual idea behind arc length (total distance) being the integral of the speed?  What exactly are you adding up?  Tiny slices of speed hypotenuses?

Ok, so the definite integral is based on t.   Starting and ending t.   For each t, you have a velocity vector distance (speed).    The integral is adding up all the speeds to get a distance traveled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *time* integral of speed is distance or length because $d=s\times t$. You're adding up small hypotenuses of speed *multiplied by* $\mathrm{d}t$, which gives small slices of distance. Loosely speaking.

You can rigorously prove the following for all $C^1$ functions $\gamma:I\to\Bbb R^n$: $$\ell(\gamma)=\int_0^1\|\gamma’\|$$For a suitable definition of length $\ell$, which is done in the first few pages [here](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/users/user317/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

There is a further equivalence of this with the Hausdorff 1-measure of the trace $\gamma(I)$.

Comment: Ok, so the definite integral is based on t.   Starting and ending t.   For each t, you have a velocity vector distance (speed).    The integral is adding up all the speeds to get a distance traveled?

Comment: Also, can you find a link or video that explains your concept?

Comment: The integral is adding up all the (tiny) distances to get the distance traveled.

Comment: @JackOfAll the integral is "adding up" all the speeds *multiplied* by time changes to get an accumulation of distance travelled. The concept is simply $d=st$.

Comment: To recap, the hypotenuse vector is the speed, since it's based on the 2 vector velocities in the x & y direction.   The integral adds up the speed vector * time (dt) to get a distance.  Right, because d=s*t.   I think it just clicked, thanks again!

Comment: @JackOfAll That’s right. You’re welcome

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for your help.  What do you do for work, and for life?  (This forum has great people yet can be impersonal)

Comment: @JackOfAll I play bad chess, good piano, do lots of maths, and go to school ;) Yourself?

Comment: You’re right the forum can feel impersonal. Strangely though I find it to be quite a small world, despite its apparent size. Many posts are from familiar faces and I can sometimes immediately know who asked or answered a certain question just from the title / first few lines

Comment: Read your bio.  I am listening to Lubomyr Melnyk now.   Try daily chess puzzles on your app.  Are you doing indep. maths work or school assignments or both?

Comment: @JackOfAll Funny thing is, I'm rated 2300 in chess.com puzzles but I'm flaky when it comes to real matches. Anyway, for the past two years I've placed a heavy focus on doing independent maths work, teaching myself using MSE and other things. School assignments don't come close to the content here on MSE. I hope you like Lubomyr, I admit most of his pieces are quite long - a barrier of entry? A nice short one is "Sunset".

Comment: 2300 is huge, I wonder what your match rating is?

Comment: @JackOfAll The match rating is nowhere near that, bizarrely. 1100 Blitz and 1300 Rapid. I just grinded puzzles in one of the lockdowns

Comment: Wow, that is a huge delta.  Seems like you're an average human player with room for growth!     Have you ever tried the liChess app?   That is more open source grassroots vibe than chess.com.   Maybe like Android vs. iPhone, LOL

Comment: @JackOfAll No I haven’t, I guess it’s just a matter of what you’re used to. An embarrassingly huge delta indeed. I can beat the $2200$ bots but flop against $1100$ humans (timing being an important factor)